# Confused about binary search trees (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I have a problem that I need to complete:

> We can represent a nonempty binary tree by list (root left_subtree 
>   right_subtree) and the empty tree by the empty list.   Each binary
>   search tree with integer labels can be considered  representing a set
>   of integers. Write a function which, given a set of integers  S as a
>   bst and an integer x, returns both the set of all the integers less
>   than x  and that of all the integers greater than x as bst’s. Use a
>   pair rather than a  list to represent the resulting sets.

I'm very new to Scheme. I've built trees using SML as well as prolog, but can't seem to get a hold of what I need to do for Scheme. Could anyone help me out and guide me towards this goal? Is my tree suppose to just look like this?

(list value left right)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's one way to define a tree. Just so long as you make a proper ADT and use it consistently, it shouldn't matter after you've defined it.

```
(define (make-tree root left right) 
  (list root left right))

(define (right tree)
 (caddr tree))

(define (left tree)
 (cadr tree))

(define (root tree)
 (car tree))

(define (empty-tree? tree)
  (null? tree))

(define empty-tree '())

(define (leaf? tree)
 (and (empty-tree? (left tree)) (empty-tree? right tree)))

(define (split-tree-at tree x)
 (let ((less ...)
       (more ...))     
  (cons less more))

(define (in-tree-below-x tree x) ;;assuming a sorted tree
  (cond ((empty-tree? tree) (empty-tree))
        ((>= (root tree) x)
         (in-tree-below (left tree) x))
        (else (make-tree (root tree) 
                         (left tree)
                         (in-tree-below-x (right tree) x)))))
```

Comment: Your `make-tree` uses `value` as a free variable?  Idiomatically `(define right caddr)`?

Comment: why `>=` in `(>= (root tree) x)` in `in-tree-below-x`? Shouldn't `==` be a special case? Or do you allow for duplicates in a tree? The insertion procedure should really be shown/discussed here too, perhaps.

Comment: I'm just 'greater than or equal to" instead of "not less than". Duplicates in the tree shouldn't make a difference, as long as it's sorted even though a set in simplified form will not have duplicates. According to the original problem nothing is done with integers equal to x. 'in-tree-below-x' should take a sorted binary tree of integers, left-less right-greater and return the subset on integers in that original set less than x, represented itself as a BST.

Comment: OK, so you *do* allow for duplicates in the tree. I was thinking about special case where tree is w/out duplicates; then on `(= (root tree) x)` we could just return `(left tree)` right away. (BTW I didn't get notified of your reply; without "@" it works only when there's only one non-OP participant in the comments).